# SSH from host into virtual machine over tor

Tags: configuration, ssh, virtual-machine

### Context

After having written a script that automatically sets up a `Leader` machine and `Follower` machine to allow the `Leader` machine to `ssh` into the `Follower`over `tor` using `torsocks`, I am experiencing some difficulties accessing the `Follower` inside the virtualbox from the `Leader` (the host).

### Functionalities

- I can

```
torsocks ssh -p 22 <follower username>@<follower onion domain>
```

from `Follower` into `Follower`. However, I **cannot* ssh from `Leader` into `Follower` over tor.

- I can:

```
ssh -p 2222 <follower username>@127.0.0.1
```

From `Leader` into `Follower`.

### Port Forwarding Configuration in Virtualbox

The above functionalities are facilitated by the following port-forwarding settings on the Ubuntu virtual box image using:

- HostIP=127.0.0.1,
- Host Port=2222,
- GuestIP=10.0.x.y, (Output of `Hostname -I` on `Follower`)
- GuestPort=22

### Torrc Configuration

The `/etc/tor/torrc` content on the `Follower` device is:

```
# SocksPort 9051
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/ssh
HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22
```

The `SocksPort 9051` was aimed at allowing the `Leader` device `ssh` access into the `Follower`, but it did not work, and it prevented the `Follower` from `ssh` accessing itself over tor.

### Question

How can I ensure the `Leader` is able to `ssh` into the `Follower` over tor? (E.g. which port settings should be used in the `/etc/tor/torrc` file, and in the port forwarding settings in virtualbox and in the ssh commands?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the `/etc/tor/torrc` configuration of the Leader, which still had content:

```
SocksPort 9051
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/ssh
HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22
```

Due to previous debugging/developer efforts. After removing the `SocksPort 9051` from that file, and restarting the tor service with:

```
sudo systemctl enable tor.service
sudo systemctl reload tor
```

I was able to start tor without sudo using `tor` in another terminal. This then allowed me to ssh into the Follower device over tor with:

```
torsocks ssh <Follower Username>@<some_onion_domain>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need Tor's DNS port on the Leader to be in `/etc/resolv.conf` as a primary one, so dot-onion hostname for Follower will be resolvable into Tor's virtual network mapped. Your problem starts when the SSH tries to resolve dot-onion name - it fails.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Would you perhaps be willing to increase the specificity of your answer? I experienced some difficulties in determining: Where do I find Tor's DNS port on the Leader? How do I make it a `primary one`? Should the Tor's DNS port on the Leader be in the `/etc/resolve.conf` of the Leader in the `/etc/resolve.conf` of the Follower?

Comment: on the Leader - on the place **where you need to resolve from**. Tor DNS port is ste up by you in torrc of the local tor instance - IP and port, and it should be the first line in resolv.conf for a simple setup